# How to pass blank textbox value as null to binded datetime

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, data-binding

As per tags, this is an Entity Framework, C#, Winforms question.

I have a textbox data bound to a nullable datetime field in my entity. I want to pass a null value back to the entity when I delete the contents of the textbox and leave it blank.

Textbox CausesValidation property = true. When I delete the contents of the textbox, I'm unable to leave it without entering in a valid date.

Here is my Validating event

```
private void txtDueDateDetail_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    string errorMsg;
    if (!ValidDate(txtDueDateDetail.Text, out errorMsg))
    {
        // Cancel the event and select the text to be corrected by the user.
        e.Cancel = true;
        txtDueDateDetail.Select(0, txtDueDateDetail.Text.Length);

        // Set the ErrorProvider error with the text to display. 
        this.epNew.SetError(txtDueDateDetail, errorMsg);
    }

    Debug.Write("text: " + txtDueDateDetail.Text);
}

public bool ValidDate(string pTextDate, out string errorMessage)
{
    DateTime tempDate;
    errorMessage = "";

    if (pTextDate.Length == 0)
    {
        //pass a null date...how?
        return true;
    }

    DateTime.TryParse(pTextDate, out tempDate);
    if (tempDate == DateTime.MinValue)
    {
        errorMessage = "date must be in format MM/dd/yyyy";
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Any ideas would be helpful.

Comment: As much as I know your line txtDueDateDetail.Text = null will never work because the text property of a TextBox is never null. If your read back the value immediatly you get an empty string, not null. I will try to bind a different property (e.g Tag) and, in the validating event, update that property, but I stop here because I don't know how to work with EF.

Answer (score 4):

Considering your initial approach, did you try setting [`Binding.NullValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.binding.nullvalue.aspx) to empty string? You can do it programmatically as follows:

```
txtDueDateDetail.DataBindings["Text"].NullValue = "";
```

As per [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.binding.nullvalue.aspx), assigning an empty string to `NullValue` is not the same as assigning `null` (which is its default value).

Your final solution is fine. I considered implementing it before I read about the `NullValue` property. To me, its drawback is that it diminishes the usefulness of data binding, because that way I end up manually assigning the changed value back to the datasource -- and I expected data binding to do this for me.

Comment: thanks for the post. I stumbled upon this MS How To as well. [How to: Bind Windows Forms Controls to DBNull Database Values](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y0h25we8.aspx) If I need to edit this section, I'll see if I can use the above solution.

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to get around the null datetime validation, so I turned off validation on the field [CausesValidation = FALSE] and performed my own validation within the Leave event.

```
 public bool ValidDate(string pTextDate, out DateTime? pDate, out string errorMessage)
    {
        DateTime tempDate;
        errorMessage = "";
        pDate = null;
        if (pTextDate.Length == 0)
        {
            //pass null date here...
            return true;
        }
        DateTime.TryParse(pTextDate, out tempDate);

        if (tempDate == DateTime.MinValue)
        {
            errorMessage = "date must be in format MM/dd/yyyy";
            return false;
        }
        pDate = tempDate;
        return true;
    }

    private void txtDueDateDetail_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string errorMsg;
        DateTime? outDate;
        if (!ValidDate(txtDueDateDetail.Text, out outDate, out errorMsg))
        {
            txtDueDateDetail.Select(0, txtDueDateDetail.Text.Length);
        }
        else
        {
            int CID = Convert.ToInt32(txtChargebackIDDetail.Text);
            var temp = (from c in chg.ChargeBackks
                        where c.ID == CID
                        select c).FirstOrDefault();
            temp.DueDate = outDate;
        }
        this.epNew.SetError(txtDueDateDetail, errorMsg);

    }
```

Functional... but not the best solution IMO.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and came to this solution.  The binding is controlled by a function which added an  event handler to OnValidating.  In this event handler by reflection we are setting the underlying entity property to either null or the value in the textbox.  This is the key which will allow validation to pass - you must set the underlying entity field to null.  Even handling e.Cancel does not help.

The call to the binding looks like this:

```
AddDateBinding(Me.txtPhantomBlockIrrDate, Me.bsPhantomBlock, "IRRADIATE_DATE")

  Public Sub AddDateBinding(control As Control, bs As BindingSource, field As String)
        Dim controlProperty As String = ""

        If TypeOf (control) Is TextBox Then
            controlProperty = "Text"
        End If
        If TypeOf (control) Is ComboBox Then
            controlProperty = "SelectedValue"
        End If

        control.DataBindings.Add(New System.Windows.Forms.Binding(controlProperty, bs, field, True, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnValidation, Nothing, "MM/dd/yyyy"))
        AddHandler control.Validating, AddressOf DateValidating

    End Sub

    Public Sub DateValidating(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs)
        e.Cancel = False
        Try
            If CType(sender, Control).Text = "" Then
                e.Cancel = False
                Dim fieldName As String = CType(sender, Control).DataBindings(0).BindingMemberInfo.BindingField
                Dim bs As BindingSource = CType(CType(sender, Control).DataBindings(0).DataSource, BindingSource)
                Dim propInfo As Reflection.PropertyInfo = bs.Current.GetType().GetProperty(fieldName)
                propInfo.SetValue(bs.Current, Nothing, Nothing)
            Else
                e.Cancel = False
                Dim fieldName As String = CType(sender, Control).DataBindings(0).BindingMemberInfo.BindingField
                Dim bs As BindingSource = CType(CType(sender, Control).DataBindings(0).DataSource, BindingSource)
                Dim propInfo As Reflection.PropertyInfo = bs.Current.GetType().GetProperty(fieldName)
                propInfo.SetValue(bs.Current, CType(sender, Control).Text, Nothing)
            End If

        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    End Sub
```